# Using Hue - Pig Editor, How can I feed param_file to pig script?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hue

We can feed params using Hue - Pig Editor. But, how can I feed param file to pig script using Hue.

From grunt shell, we use following command to feed param file.

```
$pig -param_file /tmp/pig_params.txt test.pig
```

The above thing I want to do from Hue's Pig Editor. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

The Pig Editor has a 'Properties' section with a 'Pig Parameter' list.

You can enter there

- input /user/data
- -param input=/user/data
- -optimizer_off SplitFilter
- -verbose

Latest Hue version: http://demo.gethue.com/pig